# Julia Plots package takes a lot of time to load

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, julia

I am learning to use the `Plots` package in Julia. But it takes literally 2 to 3 minutes for it to load and the same is the case with my first plot. All the later ones are fine.

Is there any issue with my package installation or something?

I did have a lot of artifacts downloading errors while installing the Plots package, could that be the reason?

I couldn't find any issue raised regarding the same on Github either. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Plots historically takes a long time to load. What is your Julia version? The load time is significantly improved in newer versions of Julia (1.5+).

Comment: Try going to discourse.julialang.org and searching for "time to first plot". You should find lots of commentary.

Comment: FWIW on a ~10 year old i7 I get on Julia 1.6: `julia> @time using Plots
  4.540539 seconds` and `julia> @time display(plot(rand(10)))
 12.086300 seconds` so 2-3 minutes is definitely excessive unless you're running on a very underpowered machine

Comment: Apparently, my installation somehow was wrong. The gr backend didn't install properly. Pkg build helped. But it still takes around 10 second to load Plots and 20 something for first plot. But I guess mine is i5 so could be the reason for this delay. Anyway.

But the question still remains, why is it slow though?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `Plots` package took "forever" to load / precompile in `julia` was really to my dismay and deterred me from trying out `julia` more.

As pointed out in the comments, there is a long thread [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/using-plots-takes-20-seconds-or-more/7061) where this is discussed, and alternative packages for plotting (e.g. [Gnuplot.jl](https://github.com/gcalderone/Gnuplot.jl)) are suggested. It is also pointed out that this has improved in the newer releases.

When I compare 1.4.2 and 1.6.1 (the latest stable as of July 2021) on my machine I typically get for 1.4.2

```
julia> @time using Plots
22.288406 seconds (17.85 M allocations: 979.523 MiB, 2.84% gc time)

julia> @time using Plots
  1.782150 seconds (1.74 M allocations: 81.678 MiB, 8.05% gc time)

julia> @time using Plots
  0.000238 seconds (486 allocations: 25.547 KiB)

julia> @time using Plots
  0.000212 seconds (486 allocations: 25.547 KiB)
```

(where the time for the first `using` varies between 18 and 23 seconds), whereas 1.6.1 is significantly faster and uses only half the memory:

```
julia> @time using Plots
  4.860129 seconds (6.87 M allocations: 502.634 MiB, 7.64% gc time, 0.14% compilation time)

julia> @time using Plots
  0.000099 seconds (81 allocations: 5.969 KiB)

julia> @time using Plots
  0.000094 seconds (81 allocations: 5.969 KiB)
```

with the time for the first `using` varying between 4 and 6 seconds (and already the second `using` is as fast as the third; I'll leave it to more experienced people to comment on this). This is definitely an improvement.